# How to Dynamically Change LinearLayout Orientation Depending on Device Orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout

How do I change the orientation of a LinearLayout when a device changes orientation? What changes would be needed in the *.xml's associated *.kt file?

For example, the device is in Portrait and displays a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation. When the device turns and becomes Landscape, the LinearLayout should have a horizontal orientation.

I imagine that two different layouts would be called depending on the configuration change but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use separate folders for your layouts : `layout` for portrait mode and `layout-land` for landscape mode, and put two separate xml files `with the same name` in each one.

One of xml files with LinearLayout with a vertical orientation and another xml file with LinearLayout with horizontal orientation.

For instance look at [How to Add/Create Landscape Layout in Android Studio](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/add-create-landscape-layout-android-studio.html)

Comment: Would changes would be needed in the *.kt file?

Comment: No there should be no change in your Activities and Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var linearLayout: LinearLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout)

    // Check the current orientation and set the initial layout orientation
    updateOrientation(resources.configuration.orientation)

    // Register a configuration change listener
    registerOrientationListener()
}

private fun registerOrientationListener() {
    val listener = object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
        override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
            if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return

            val newOrientation = if (orientation in 45..134 || orientation in 225..314) {
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            } else {
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            }

            updateOrientation(newOrientation)
        }
    }

    if (listener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        listener.enable()
    }
}

private fun updateOrientation(newOrientation: Int) {
    linearLayout.orientation = if (newOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
    } else {
        LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    }
  }
}
```