# widgets get stuck and overlap when screen rotation in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, screen-orientation

This is for my curiosity for learning as this is my simple mini project 
A LOGIN SCREEN

However the layout appears just fine [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWgFS.jpg) on portrait mode, but when I rotate the screen is shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebyUG.jpg)

Just want all the widgets to placed perfectly according to the screen mode.

My guess is that it has something to do with main xml file for the layout and widget design. 
I override the onConfigurationChanged method but it didn't work
I thought its better idea to post link of the code then to post it here since it's too many lines

[Here is the Project](https://github.com/ImDineshSharma/Login1/tree/master/app/src/main)

Comment: One solution will be creating a separate xml layout for landscape mode as explained : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975867/how-to-dynamically-change-linearlayout-orientation-depending-on-device-orientati/57975937#57975937

Comment: I did create the sepreate xml files. One is as linear layout with screen orientation vertical inside layout folder and Another as linear layout with screen orientation horizantal inside layout-land folder but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorLink="#808080"
        android:textColorHint="#808080"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:autofillHints="Password"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#808080"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#00ffff"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/registration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/registration">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Register Now"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/footer"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/footer"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#00ffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LoginLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/LoginLayout"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LoginLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When I applied it everything changed like the positions, the theme etc., by the way what changes did you make and Why

Comment: your layout is specific to the screen position and i have changed it into the relative to other views as per requirements